# Определить площадь фигуры в метрах из пикселей на фотографии

Tags: c#, .net

Как определить площадь в метрах. В программу с компьютера загружаются фотографии (разных размеров). Пользователь с помощью определения точек на фотографии (координаты нажатия мыши) определяет площадь простого многоугольника в пикселях. Как точно преобразовать пиксели в метры, если фотографии и мониторы имеют разные размеры. Возможно, реализовать калибровку пользователю путём определения метража на фотографии, предварительно зная длину определённого предмета, и исходя из этого двигаться? Или есть какие ещё варианты?

Comment: Точных вариантов скорее всего нет в природе, так как для таких измерений нужна 3д сцена, а не фотография. Вы и глазами не сможете определить расстояние, куда это компьютеру сделать.

Comment: У фотографии есть размеры ширина x высота и есть разрешение dpi - количество точек на дюйм. Этого достаточно, чтобы вычислить размер пикселя в метрической системе мер. И площать измеряется в квадратных метрах, а не в метрах.